# Need some good examples of a VB application talking to MySQL

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net

I hope someone can help. I was "volunteered" to come up with an application for a local charity group. What they are looking for is a system that will track:

- Person
- Help provided to them
- Case worker
- etc.

They picked me to help as I have done some computer work and for them that means I'm an expert :-(   What they want is for me to use a Visual Basic front-end talking to MySQL. I know enough to realize that most systems DON'T work out first time and the chances are even less if that person (Me) has not much experience.

So I am hoping someone can help me. All I want is for someone who works with VB/MySQL to give me some possible links / suggestions on where I could look for some tutorials or example systems. I really hope some person out there can help me.

Answer (score 0):

See the first [result](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-1) I've got from Google for vb .net mysql... I think it will help you to start something.